# How to check FileMode in FileStream instance

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to check if `FileStream` got to `MyMethod` is in `Append` mode.

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod(FileStream file)
    {
        if ( /* file is in `Append` mode */ )
        {
            /* doing something (ref1) */
        }
        else
        {
            /* doing something else (ref2) */
        }
    }
}
```

And example of using:

```
MyClass.MyMethod(File.Open("x.x", FileMode.Append)); // should run code marked as `ref1`
MyClass.MyMethod(File.Open("x.x", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)); // should run code marked as `ref2`
```

Is it possible to check this? Is it possible to check similarly `FileAccess` given to `File.Open` method? What should I do if I have `FileStream` as a field of class and I want to check this in the contract invariant?

Comment: Why to complex things. Pass the `FileMode` as second parameter to method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileStream` class does not expose that information to you. You will have to remember which value of `FileMode` you used, and pass that information to your method.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't solve my problem. What should I do if I have `FileStream` as a field in my class and I want to check its `FileMode` in a contract (especially in `Contract.Invariant` method)? I am sorry I haven't said it in my question, but I tried to ask my question the simpliest I could.

Comment: Yes, it does solve your problem. Since the class won't tell you what `FileMode` you passed, you have to remember it.

Comment: But the `Contract.Invariant` method is using for checking state of specific instance after every call of each public method of class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When I run the `Contract.Invariant` method I am not interested in what is `FileMode` artificially added to the class, but rather what is actual state of `FileStream` field.

Comment: I understand that. I think you need to understand the consequences of the fact that the `FileStream` does not remember what `FileMode` was used to create it. Since it won't remember that, you will have to.

Comment: I see. I am really disappointed with that... I had seen code in Python which checked this in any moment and I started considering what is the way to do this in C#. But thanks a lot for your answer :)